# How to fix this error in azure PowerShell : "Can not remove tag/tag value because it's being referenced by other resources."

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Im want to delete the tags from large number of VM in microsoft azure. 
But I get this error : Can not remove tag/tag value because it's being referenced by other resources. What I need to do and how to fix this error???

```
Remove-AzureRmTag -Name "sada"
```

This code i have used to remove sada from all my Azure Virtual Machines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this means this tag is being used by some resource in azure, you can only remove unused tags with this cmdlet. so your only option is to remove all those tags from existing resource (you can use a fairly simple powershell script for that, or just mass tagging from the portal). and then you can run this cmdlet.

something like this:

```
$res = Get-AzResource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$res.ForEach{
    if ( $_.tags.ContainsKey('sada') ) {
        $_.tags.Remove('sada')
    }
    $_ | Set-AzResource -Tags $_.tags
}
```

Comment: I will be grateful if you give me this PowerShell script. I cant find anything besides this (

Comment: check updated answer, this might not be it exactly, but should be close enough

Comment: if i want to set value too ?

Answer (score 0):

*You cannot delete a tag or value that is currently applied to a resource or resource group. Before using Remove-AzTag, use the Tag parameter of the Set-AzResourceGroup cmdlet to delete the tag or values from the resource or resource group.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-aztag?view=azps-4.8.0#description

The Solution is simple:

```
Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.id -Tag $removeTags -Operation Delete
```