# Azure: delete all tags

Tags: azure, powershell, tags

I have script to delete all Tags.
I get Tags yet:

Get-AzTag

Name        Count

---

displayName 2
App         1
Department  1
Env         1
Owner       1

I can't find which resource is attached.

Get-AzResource

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: Can you please be more specific and clear about the question?

Comment: Hi @RithwikBojja-MT , I would like to delete all Tags in a subscription. I deleted all resources and there are any resource or RG now, but I can't delete Tags. It seems there is some resource (I don't know where) attached still.

When I try to remove Tag via next Powershell's command **remove-aztag**, I get result: 
**Remove-AzTag: Can not remove tag/tag value because it's being referenced by other resources**

If I run command **get-aztag** I can see there is 1 resource :(

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gill-Bates, According to [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162372/how-to-fix-this-error-in-azure-powershell-can-not-remove-tag-tag-value-becaus) it says,

> A tag or value that is already associated with a resource or resource group cannot be removed. Before using Remove-AzTag, use the Tag parameter of the Set-AzResourceGroup cmdlet to delete the tag or values from the resource or resource group.

[image]

[image]

```
Update-AzTag -ResourceId xyz-Tag $tags -Operation Delete
```

***xyz is resource id***

***Output:***
[image]

***References taken from:***

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11761
- https://debbiesmspowerbiazureblog.home.blog/2020/04/27/azure-tagging-with-powershell-example/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54162388